# Delay a respawn of a service

Tags: services, sysvinit

How can I delay the start of my service using respawn?

I am configuring my service in inittab like this:

```
vpn:2345:respawn:/etc/init.d/openvpn restart
```

and I am getting respawn too fast error and the service is disabled for 5 minutes.
how can I make respawn wait some time before trying to restart the service?

I am running a custom distribution of linux for ARM architecture (debian packages for ARM can be installed in this distribution)
linux kernel is : linux-3.10.x

Thanks!

Comment: Don't run it from `init`, rather install something like DJB's `daemontools`.

Comment: make a cron job for stopping and another for starting it at another time

Comment: You already asked this at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/394332/ .

Comment: The init.d scripts return very quickly. They don't work well in an inittab respawn entry. The regular init system ought to be able to handle what you want. What Linux or Unix distribution and version number are you running?

Comment: @JdeBP No, she didn't.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick: I added details about my linux distribution. thanks

Answer (score -1):

If a service crashes on restart then it is not going to work if you delay its restart. But you can do that by putting a wrapper script in `inittab` that looks like this:

```
#! /bin/bash
sleep 60
exec /path/to/service
```